# no-cache CSS file on Google Cloud Storage not updating

Tags: metadata, google-cloud-storage, cache-control

I have a CSS stylesheet for a static website on Google Cloud Storage with its metadata cache-control set to no-cache that I can't get to refresh. The HTML pages with equal settings refresh as expected. What steps can I take to make the CSS changes public?

note: If I open the object directly I can see the changes. The "public link" however does not update.

Comment: If you "`curl`" the URL for the CSS stylesheet or log the HTTP request in your browser, what headers do you see on the CSS asset?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue too and haven't found a very satisfactory solution.  Instead, I add a query param to the file I need to update, so it'd look like: `stylesheet.css?nocache=1506661352`